# fill in dataframe with two for loops and if condition in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames, one looks something like this:

df1:

```
x    y    Counts
a    b    1
a    c    3
b    c    2
c    d    1
```

The other one has both as index and as columns the list of unique values in the first two columns:

df2

```
   a  b  c  d
a
b
c
d
```

What I wouldl like to do is to fill in the second DataFrame with values from the first one, given the intersection of column and index is the same line from the first DataFrame, e.g.:

```
   a    b   c   d
a   0   1   3   0
b   1   0   2   0
c   3   2   0   1
d   0   0   1   0
```

While I try to use two for loops with a double if-condition, it makes the computer block (given that a real DataFrame contains more than 1000 rows).

The piece of code I am trying to implement (and which makes calculations apparently too 'heavy' for a computer to perform):

```
for i in df2.index:
    for j in df2.columns:
        if (i==df1.x.any() and j==df1.y.any()):
            df2.loc[i,j]=df1.Counts
```

Important to notice, the list of unique values (i.e., index and columns in the second DataFrame) is longer than the number of rows in the first columns, in my example they coincided.

If it is of any relevance, the first dataframe represents basically combinations of words in the first and in the second column and their occurences in the text. Occurrences are basically the weights of edges. 
So, I am trying to create a matrix so as to plot a graph via igraph. I chose to first create a DataFrame, then its values taken as an array pass to igraph. 
As far as I could understand, python-igraph cannot use dataframe to plot a graph, a numpy array only. 
Tried some of the soulutions suggested for the similar issues, nothing worked out so far.

Any suggestions to improve my question are warmly welcomed (it's my first question here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

#df = pd.read_clipboard()
#df2 = df.copy()
df3=df2.pivot(index='x',columns='y',values='Counts')
print df3
print
new=sorted((set(df3.columns.tolist()+df3.index.tolist())))
df3 = df3.reindex(new,columns=new).fillna(0).applymap(int)
print df3
```

output:

```
y    b    c    d
x               
a  1.0  3.0  NaN
b  NaN  2.0  NaN
c  NaN  NaN  1.0

y  a  b  c  d
x            
a  0  1  3  0
b  0  0  2  0
c  0  0  0  1
d  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Do you know what Blue in the Face mask is for?  I have it as well and it's bothering me that I don't know. :-)

Comment: @piRSquared Yeah the blue part is supposed to fit on the face (as the name suggests: Blue on the Face) but it's kinda big. If you try to wear it, I guess the best fit is the pointy edge of grey cone should come in the middle of the nose. Click on the mask, drag it and overlap on some face.

Comment: Thank you, Mohammed! It did work, but this solution(pivot) makes me "loose" some values I should not loose, e.g. 'a' as a column, and 'd' as a row. Although the values are present in another way (the whole dataframe would be symmetric), I should necessarily have a square matrix. I thought of adding 'missing' rows and columns manually, but once again it takes too much time.

Comment: @NellyM piRSquared's solution would work for you. Just fill the NaN with zeros.

Comment: @NellyM Modified my solution. Check if it works for you.

Comment: It does work, and it works perfectly both for a 'small' example, and for the dataframe of more than 1200 rows and columns. Thank you, @Mohammad Yusuf Ghazi and @piRSquared! What an elegant solution you came up with!

Answer (score 3):

`stack` `df2` and `fillna` with `df1`

```
idx = pd.Index(np.unique(df1[['x', 'y']]))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=idx, columns=idx)

df2.stack(dropna=False).fillna(df1.set_index(['x', 'y']).Counts) \
    .unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)

   a  b  c  d
a  0  1  3  0
b  0  0  2  0
c  0  0  0  1
d  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: By the way. This is pretty dope. Can't parse in my head what you just did here. Maybe I'll print and see all the parts. :)

Comment: Thank you, @piRSquared! it looks exactly what I need, but in practice I get the whole DataFrame filled with NaN values only. Checked it twice on the real dataset, and then tried with a 'small' example, the one with 4 rows and columns, and I got all the NaN values again. Can't figure out what I am missing.

Comment: @piRSquared Check my solution. It works for now but will it fail if x and y are not sorted in the original dataframe?